# Concatenating characters/numbers to represent variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

In this script I have three PHP variables that I want to output using Javascript for testing purposes. $Q1, $Q2 and $Q3 respectively. I want to output all of them through a for loop adding Q and their index (1, 2 and 3) together. Ex. If I want to output var Q2 which is $Q2, on the second iteration of the for loop it would have to be something like 'Q' + i where i is 2.

See below:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors','On');

$Q1 = 'Question 1';
$Q2 = 'Question 2';
$Q3 = 'Question 3';

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>


<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var Q1 = "<?php Print($Q1); ?>";
 var Q2 = "<?php Print($Q2); ?>";
 var Q3 = "<?php Print($Q3); ?>";

 for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
 {
    alert (eval("Q" + i)); 

 }

 </script> 
</body>

</html>
```

I tried using eval but I feel it is more for arithmetic purposes. What can I use to substitute it?

Comment: Did u already tried this `eval("Q"+1) `??

Comment: @bhushya It changes nothing, I will edit my question incorporating it though so people don't suggest it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using an array?, you can even loop on the php to generate the questions

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors','On');

$Q1 = 'Question 1';
$Q2 = 'Question 2';
$Q3 = 'Question 3';

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>


<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var Question= new Array( "<?php Print($Q1); ?>","<?php Print($Q2); ?>","<?php Print($Q3); ?>");

 for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
 {
    alert (Question[i]); 

 }
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Good answer. Il try adding a loop within the PHP as well

Answer (score 2):

Try something like :

```
alert(eval('Q'+i));
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval` can be dangerous

A better approach would be convert your variables to array and pass the array to javascript using `json_encode`

PHP

```
$q= array('Question 1', 'Question 2','Question 3');
```

HTML

```
var questions = <? echo json_encode($q) ?>;

 for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
 {
    alert (questions[i]); 

 }
```